# Fast counting of characters in character vector

Tags: r

I have a very long vector of single characters i.e. `somechars<-c("A","B","C","A"...)` (length is somewhere in the millions)

what is the fastest way I can count the total occurrences of say "A" and "B" in this vector?
I have tried using `grep` and `lapply` but they all take so long to execute.

My current solution is:

```
tmp<-table(somechars)
sum(tmp["A"],tmp["B"])
```

But this still takes a while to compute. Is there some faster way I can be doing this? Or are there any packages I can be using to that does this already faster? I've looked into the `stringr` package but they use a simple grep.

Comment: I assume this is related to your `table(..., exclude)` question.  What, exactly, are you trying to do and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @Joshua I was actually just curious how widely accepted the!  Argument is throughout r.and I'm trying to count letters in a DNA sequence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought that this would be fastest...

```
sum(somechars %in% c('A', 'B'))
```

And, it is faster than...

```
sum(c(somechars=="A",somechars=="B"))
```

But not faster than...

```
sum(somechars=="A"|somechars=="B")
```

But this is qualified by how many comparisons you make... which brings me back to my first guess.  Once you want to sum more than 2 letters using the %in% version is the fastest.

Comment: the result with `%in%` is interesting, but according to my results it depends on R version. In which version of R did you measure it?

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd solutions are unnecessarilly slow, see my post.

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm going to have to try a combination of your answer and Tomas TS answer

Answer (score 8):

Regular expressions are expensive.  You can get the result in your question with exact comparison.

```
> somechars <- sample(LETTERS, 5e6, TRUE)
> sum(c(somechars=="A",somechars=="B"))
[1] 385675
> system.time(sum(c(somechars=="A",somechars=="B")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.416   0.072   0.487
```

UPDATED to include timings from the OP and other answers.  Also included a test larger than the 2-character case.

```
> library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark( replications=5, order="relative",
+   grep = sum(grepl("A|B",somechars)),
+   table = sum(table(somechars)[c("A","B")]),
+   c = sum(c(somechars=="A",somechars=="B")),
+   OR = sum(somechars=="A"|somechars=="B"),
+   IN = sum(somechars %in% c("A","B")),
+   plus = sum(somechars=="A")+sum(somechars=="B") )
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
6  plus            5   4.289 1.000000     3.836    0.436          0         0
3     c            5   4.991 1.163675     4.156    0.804          0         0
5    IN            5   5.480 1.277687     4.549    0.880          0         0
4    OR            5   5.574 1.299604     5.000    0.544          0         0
1  grep            5  16.426 3.829797    16.205    0.172          0         0
2 table            5  17.834 4.158079    12.793    4.884          0         0
> 
> benchmark( replications=5, order="relative",
+   grep = sum(grepl("A|B|C|D",somechars)),
+   table = sum(table(somechars)[c("A","B","C","D")]),
+   c = sum(c(somechars=="A",somechars=="B",
+             somechars=="C",somechars=="D")),
+   OR = sum(somechars=="A"|somechars=="B"|
+            somechars=="C"|somechars=="D"),
+   IN = sum(somechars %in% c("A","B","C","D")),
+   plus = sum(somechars=="A")+sum(somechars=="B")+
+          sum(somechars=="C")+sum(somechars=="D") )
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
5    IN            5   5.513 1.000000     4.464    1.004          0         0
6  plus            5   8.603 1.560493     7.705    0.860          0         0
3     c            5  10.283 1.865228     8.648    1.560          0         0
4    OR            5  12.348 2.239797    10.849    1.464          0         0
2 table            5  17.960 3.257754    12.877    4.921          0         0
1  grep            5  21.692 3.934700    21.405    0.192          0         0
```

Comment: the concatenation of both vectors `somechars=='A'` and `somechars=='B'` is not necessary and slows down the computation.

Comment: @TomasT. You will make more friends and influence more people on SO if you try and make your comments positive, rather than pointing out that answers have flaws.  For example, you could have written "Nice answer - this will be even faster if you don't concatenate A and B"

Comment: Good point, Andrie, thanks. I just focused on the thing itself and that's possibly not the best approach...

Comment: This is all very useful, but ... it would be most interesting (to me) to compare the orders-of-magnitude differences between (1) regular-expression based solutions; (2) `table` as suggested by the OP; and (3) the various flavours being discussed here [because the time differences for a vector of length 1e7, while threefold between various solutions presented here, are still on the order of 1 second ...]

Comment: Joshua, do you run your system.time multiple times?  I don't get 'c' faster than '|' versions except in the noise (they are close). (2.13.2 64 bit, Mac OS X Lion)

Comment: @John: I only ran it once.  I've replaced my `system.time` benchmarks with some from the rbenchmark package and I get similar results (2.13.2 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10).  FWIW, I prefer the `%in%` solution, but didn't think of it when I initially answered.  @BenBolker: your wish is my command.

Comment: thanks Joshua... I tend to report the average of a few `system.time` calls if I report a time but, after I looked at it a bit, `%in%` did seem the obvious answer so I didn't go into that much detail.  I find the biggest issue is the variance in the first time the call is made.  This makes sense if you even know a little bit about caching, lazy loading, etc.  Even `benchmark` I run twice.  This is now a very detailed answer with a variety of lessons in it.

Answer (score 2):

#### According to my expectations, `sum(x=='A') + sum(x=='B')` is the fastest.

Unlike the other solutions proposed here it doesn't have to do any other unnecessary operation like concatenating the intermediate results using `c(..)` or `|`. **It does just the counting** - the only thing which is really needed!

R 2.13.1:

```
> x <- sample(letters, 1e7, TRUE)
> system.time(sum(x=='A') + sum(x=='B'))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.75    0.16    1.98 
> system.time(sum(c(x=='A', x=='B')))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.40    0.23    4.27 
> system.time(sum(x=='A' | x=='B'))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.25    0.19    2.54
```

But really interesting is comparison of `sum(x %in% c('A','B'))` with the first, fastest solution. In R 2.13.1 it takes the same time, in R 2.11.1, it is much slower (same result as John reported)! So I'd recommend to use the first solution: `sum(x=='A')+sum(x=='B')`.

Comment: Your recommend solution does not generalize as well (e.g. what if you want the count of 10 characters, instead of 2?).  Not only that, but it's slower than `%in%` for more than 2 characters.  And recommending your solution because it's faster in a 1-year old version of R is a bit of a reach.  "I think we are sometimes optimizing too much - too much complication for no benefit."

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, I don't see the point of your comment - your solution `sum(c(x=='A', x=='B'))` doesn't generalize too, and furthermore is MUCH slower in all tested versions of R (37% slower in R 2.13.1). The only solution which generalizes is `%in%`, but its speed is still unpredictable and I don't now how this depends on R version, until I get response from John

Comment: I never claimed my solution was best; just that it was faster than regular expressions.  You don't have to wait on John to see how it depends on R versions.  Install several versions and test it yourself, if you're that concerned.

Comment: Note that sampling `letters` gives you lower case letters, so testing for `A` or `B` will yield a vector of all FALSE values.  The ordering of results may not change, but timings may be misleading.  You should sample from `LETTERS`.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool, tho' I didn't time-check it against Tomas' solutions, is

```
rle(sort(your_vector))
```

It's certainly the simplest solution :-) .

Comment: OP's original `table(your_vector)` does the same and is much shorter, easier and faster!

Comment: Fair enough, Tomas.  I stand down.